# My stuffed turkey is almost cooked but really no juices

Tags: baking, gammon

Stuffed turkey crown is almost cooked but there is virtually no juices how can I rectify this

Comment: What will you do with the juice?  Do you want juice to make gravy?

Answer (score 2):

I use an infusion technique, I learned from my mother. It is a bit time consuming but provides you with a nice quantity of sauce (gravy) at the end. This is good for any roast, either chicken, turkey, lamb, goat, pork, veal, etc.

For a start, I marinate/add a mix of herbs and olive oil, white wine and water to the roast. Every 20 minutes I open the oven and use a large spoon to rinse the top of the roast with the sauce. Add a little water and white wine to keep a decent quantity of sauce.

Repeat this every 20-30 minutes until the roast is ready.

If your oven dries the roast quickly, or you don't have time to repeat the infusion too often, cover the roast with aluminum foil. But remove the foil about 20 minutes before the roast is finished.

Answer (score -1):

My Thanksgiving Turkey had the same 'issue'. There was a small amount of condensed drippings on the bottom of the pan that made very good gravy, but nowhere near the liquid from previous years. That leads me to believe that there has been some change in the manufacturing/packaging of our Turkeys (in the USA) and not due to an error on your part.

(My turkey was still thoroughly cooked, moist and juicy.)

Comment: That doesn't help with a solution, maybe you could [edit] to include one?

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm up to the task of forcing the manufacture's to process their products differently. The OP didn't do anything wrong.  They just needed some reassurance that fewer 'drippings' wasn't an error on their part. Most of us will see the same results. (no offense intended)

Comment: what I meant is: OP wants a solution to get more juice using whatever turkey they have at hand. Improvement doesn't mean that something went wrong, but that something _could be better_.